# Php-Error: FATAL ERROR syntax error, unexpected '<' on line number 2

Tags: php

It is showing an error on line 2 like this  FATAL ERROR syntax error, unexpected '<' on line number 2
please tell me what I am missing here.My code is shown below

```
<?php
<footer>
<div class="container">
<center>
<p>Copyright &copy; Lifestyle Store. All Rights Reserved | Contact Us: +91 
9000000000</p>
</center>
</div>
</footer>
?>
```

Comment: You can't put HTML directly into `<?php` and `?>` block.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot just write HTML directly inside PHP, like that, Try:

```
<footer>
<div class="container">
<center>
<p>Copyright &copy; Lifestyle Store. All Rights Reserved | Contact Us: +91 
9000000000</p>
</center>
</div>
</footer>
```

Remove the `<?php` and `?>` tags.

Or add your html code inside PHP's `echo`:

```
<?php
echo '<footer>
<div class="container">
<center>
<p>Copyright &copy; Lifestyle Store. All Rights Reserved | Contact Us: +91 
9000000000</p>
</center>
</div>
</footer>';
?>
```

Comment: thnx its working now

Comment: @JAI If the solution was helpful, please be sure to accept it.